# How to create templates in JSTL JSP

Tags: jsp, jstl

Say I have a JSP page with JSTL.  I'm using c:forEach and looping over 5 different sets of objects, each very similar.  Each loop is nearly identical.. lots of duplicated code.

I'd like to make that loop a template -- such as a JSP template, but I want to pass the JSTL object(s) in the parameters.

How can I do this?

Or a more general question -- how can I create reusable HTML templates in JSP/JSTL?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use [tagfiles](http://java.sun.com/j2ee/1.4/docs/tutorial/doc/JSPTags5.html). These are JSP fragments with well-defined arguments. Should be perfect for what you need.

Answer (score 0):

well, it is not perfect but i have some reuse through parametized includes.
If you pass the name of the bean in  you can in jsp fragments access to beans vith ${xxxxScope[param.beanName]} or ${xxxxScope[param.formName][param.beanName]}